# Jackson jsonformat deserialize always in UTC

Tags: java, json, jackson, timezone, jackson2

Jackson's `jsonformat` annotation works not quite as I expected.

Let's say in Java `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
Date date = sdf.parse("1-Mar-2018");
```

The `date` object value is `1-Mar-2018 SGT`. Which is fine because my timezone is in Singapore.

Now I have a http webservice which post a json value:

```
{
  "filterDate": "01-Mar-2018"
}
```

In my bean, I annotate it with

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd-MMM-yyyy")
public void setDeliveryDate(Date deliveryDate) {
    this.deliveryDate = deliveryDate;
}
```

OK the value of `deliveryDate` is `1-Mar-2018 UTC`.

While I do this:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd-MMM-yyyy", timezone="Asia/Singapore")
public void setDeliveryDate(Date deliveryDate) {
    this.deliveryDate = deliveryDate;
}
```

It is still deserialized into `1-Mar-2018 UTC`, which I think it should be `1-Mar-2018 SGT`.

Why this behave like this?

Comment: try reading https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/jan/06/javascript-json-date-parsing-and-real-dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`timezone` parameter is meant for serialisation according to [JsonFormat documentation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html) and not for deserialisation as in your post. I don't see how it could be used for deserialisation given that [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) *"is intended to reflect coordinated universal time (UTC)"* and doesn't contain timezone information.

Consider switching to [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html), available since Java 8, if you want to specify a timezone for `deliveryDate`.

If you must use `Date` you can specify a default timezone that will be used whenever you print or format any `Date` object E.g.

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Singapore"));
System.out.println(new Date());
```

produces

> Tue Mar 06 21:15:12 SRET 2018